Why didn't Moshe have an issue with Gad and Reuven spurning Eretz Yisroel?
Bamidbar 32 portays Moshe's problem with Reuven and Gad's request to settle in Transjordan as one of potentially dissuading the Israelites from finally fighting and conquering the promised land.
Once they adequately address that concern, by pledging to lead the fight, Moshe aquieces to their request.
Why wasn't Moshe disturbed by their not wanting to enter and inherit the promised land (something that featured writ large in his own life), agreeing with the arrangement once he felt that he had sufficient assurance that their actions wouldn't lead to a repeat of the meraglim episode?

Maybe he believed that they should be free to make their own mistakes, provided there was no impact on anyone else

@JoelK Judaism is all about collective responsibility. How can you sugggest the leader of the Jewish People would let entire tribes act against G-d's will (if in fact they were)?

@shmosel maybe we have a responsibility to do the right thing specifically from a position of "free to make our own mistakes", rather than force of authority

@RabbiKaii Ultimately we're always free to make our own mistakes. That doesn't mean we're free to let each other make mistakes. Where do you see in Torah that an authority figure took the "life and let live" approach instead of pushing people to do the right thing?

@shmosel Yehoshua 24:15, Shmuel 1:8 and Melachim 1:18:21 come to mind.

I don't think any of those demonstrate that. The first and third are rhetorical, and the second is an explicit instruction from Hashem.

I notice that, while God promised and commanded the people to come and conquer the land, He didn't make a clear plan about future settlement and Templaic work. Strangely, He didn't mention coming to Jerusalem and establishing the Temple there. So it feels like those are two different narratives - one miraculous and Heavenly-inspired, covering the five books of Torah, and the other realistic and pragmatic, covering the Books of Prophets.

According to the Ramban, the East Bank (Jordan) is part of the promised land, just at a lower holiness the West Bank (Israel). Moshe just wanted them all to live on one piece of land with no natural borders (Bamidbar 21:21). Separately, Moshe accused them of being scared and they said no way (Bamidbar 32:2). This may have been so obvious because the Transjordan kings were stronger than the C'naanite ones (Bamidbar 35:14).

Nice point (+1) however even according to Ramban it is a bit strange that Moshe wouldn't take issue with their not living together with the rest of Israel nor with them living in a land of less holiness (no B"hM) and mitzvos hateluyos ba'aretz (bikkurim), particularly in light of Ramban's famous opinion regarding mitzvas yishuv EY (Bamidbar 33:53) which does not seem to include transjordan (as delineated in Bamidbar 34). All this notwithstanding Meshech Chochmah's chiddush (Devarim 11:31) and the fact that EY can become enlarged after the core land is conquered (Sifri & Ramban to ibid 11:24).

If it is part of Israel, how can he tell them they have no right to it? He wasn't happy but you gotta pick your battles. Re: 34 Why would it not include the east bank? it starts with when you go to the other side what to conquer so no need to include it. Even then the Parsha (petucha, 34:15) includes the east bank
